# Physics of explosions: just vorticity?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, navier-stokes, vorticity

eg [1](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=joyi-ig6_Kw) [2](https://youtu.be/X2wvP2gI-fI). Is it just vorticity? What's actually happening? (Similar: steam engines, volcanoes, clouds).

examples are grid-based, using "vorticity confinement" in [Phoenix FD](https://www.chaosgroup.com/phoenix-fd/maya).

**EDIT** Some techniques: "divergence control" is used to increase the smoke concentration; and fuel particles in the air may combust, further adding smoke at that point (i.e. not at the initial source of the smoke).

A reference: Feldman 2003, *Animating Suspended Particle Explosions*, ACM Trans. Graph. (Proc. SIGGRAPH) 22 (2003), 708-715

Comment: I don't think that one could tell what was the technique used for in that simulation. In fact, after the simulation was done ther is a whole post-processing for generating those rendered images that might change what you see.

Comment: @nicoguaro Thanks for having a look! The video is just the clearest example I could find of this convective fluid motion; you also see it in billowing steam engines, volcano smoke and puffy clouds (though too slow to see motion in clouds). I'm interested in _a_ way to simulate it; it doesn't have to be the specific one that happened to be used in that video. If there are several ways to achieve that motion, so much the better! I don't think rendering would change the _motion_ evident in the video... [I'll edit the Q to clarify]

Comment: It might change indeed, in Smoothed Particle Hydrodynamics you might have a less smooth solution. Like the one just after the one you suggested in the video. You can think about some post processing for that case, for example.

Comment: So, it could be done with "Smoothed Particle Hydrodynamics"? Do you have a sense for how long that simulation would take - could it be realtime? (or are you saying that it's hard to guess the actual resolution or number of particles, because the amount of smoothing hides it?) Am I right in thinking that the physical process is producing vortices; and that they are caused by pressure preventing compression? (or is it due to viscosity?)

Comment: Also, doesn't the "smoothed" in "Smoothed Particle Hydrodynamics" refer to producing a field from particles as part of evolving the motion, rather than a rendering technique?

Comment: I don't think that it's done with SPH, but I might be wrong. I don't know for how long it would take, there are techniques with the purpose of solving fast and "realistically" enough (mainly for video games). I don't know how to answer to the physical explanation. Yes, the S in SPH stands for "smoothed" but I was trying to make a point, but I might be plain wrong. Maybe you should focus in the edition and provide context for what you want and why, then maybe somebody can suggest something.

Comment: Have you taken note of the video description, which suggests either realflow http://www.realflow.com or blender https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/fluid/types/domain.html

Comment: @nicoguaro Thanks for your candour! My purpose is for video game/simulation, in smartphones - though I don't expect anything close to that video is possible in realtime. ATM I just want *some* way of simulating it, even if extremely slow. (It's obviously possible, because of the video). And, I want an understanding of the physical processes, for my own umderstanding and so I can explore different approaches, to get what I want. Unfortunately, I've found little online - it doesn't seem a focus of CFG! BTW I don't know this expression "focus in the edition" - what does it mean?

Comment: @origimbo I've been watching it offline (no description), and assumed it was just a collection of simulations from many sources, but I should have looked - thanks for checking! I'll follow up those leads.

Comment: In fact, following the attribution link gives https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=joyi-ig6_Kw, which seems to point to https://www.chaosgroup.com/phoenix-fd/maya as yet another "realistic" simulator, but a cell based one.

Comment: I meant that you should rewrite your question with the information provided as answers to questions in the comments.

Comment: @origimbo Wow! Even better, thanks again! The "attributions" link doesn't work in youtube's mobile site, but it's there in the desktop version - so I've learnt something there. The "Phoenix FD" site has some amazing videos with this kind of fluid motion (and one image titled *"VORTICITY
Simulate highly-realistic and complex vorticity effects..."* So I'm on track with "vorticity", and should be able to find out how they did it. Also, the attribution video apparently uses "123million cells" (about $500^3$).

Comment: @nicoguaro Oh, I see! A new "edition" of a book is the result of edits; editing a question results in a new "edition" of the question. :) Cute, and precise. I agree, I should focus on one question, not 3 - I'll edit. The first thing I'm interested in is the physical process. But (and maybe I'm wrong), I think if I make it too specific to my context (simulation on smartphone), I won't get any answers, because it seems impossible.

Comment: @hypergallium By simulating just inviscid Euler equation (+gravity), one can create interesting patterns of vortices. See this video of my simulator https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pA5fryVt33o (I'm using a purely Lagrangian particle method, but you can probably do that also with SPH).

Comment: @BrunoLevy Thanks, yes, can see the secondary vortices forming. I assume your scheme is incompresssible - BTW how do you achieve that with a particle system? Also, I wonder if the different densities of fluids (in Raleigh-Taylor instability) is crucial for the vorticity production in your simulation? Though, there seems only one fluid (ie type of particle).

Comment: @hypergallium Yes, the fluids are incompressible (forgot to mention it). There are two fluids with different densities, one of them (light, on the bottom) is made invisible to better see the structures in the other one (top, heavier). Incompressibility is enforced by controlling the volumes of Voronoi cells (power diagram), using optimal transport (Merigot-Gallouet scheme).